# Unable to send a Hash Map to a new Activity through putExtra

Tags: java, android

I am trying to send "HashMap pointMap" this hash map to a new activity ,
this is where i send the map ,
In oncreate method in Main2Activity class

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, OutActivity.class);

            Log.d("Null",dv.getPointMap().toString());

            myIntent.putExtra("hashMap", dv.getPointMap());
            //pass input int to next activity
            Main2Activity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
```

And in here dv is a DrawingView class it's extends View and it has method call getPointMap it returns the hashMap

And this how i receive it from next activity

```
    hashMap = (HashMap<Integer , Point>) this.getIntent().getSerializableExtra("hashMap");
```

before sending i checked whether it has any elements , in the log it shows it has elements
 but my problem is when the code runs it gives this exception

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                      Process: com.example.chalaka.myapplication, PID: 22046
>                                                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value
>   com.example.chalaka.myapplication.Point@293492bd
>                                                                                          at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1337)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:614)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Parcel.writeMap(Parcel.java:598)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1255)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:638)
>                                                                                          at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1313)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1096)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:663)
>                                                                                          at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:7335)
>                                                                                          at
>   android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2485)
>                                                                                          at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1486)
>                                                                                          at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3796)
>                                                                                          at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3744)
>                                                                                          at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:784)
>                                                                                          at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4067)
>                                                                                          at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4035)
>                                                                                          at
>   com.example.chalaka.myapplication.Main2Activity$1.onClick(Main2Activity.java:93)
>                                                                                          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4808)
>                                                                                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19918)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5536)
>                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                          at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1397)
>                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1192)

please help me to solve this...

Comment: Try use Parcelable: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html insted of HashMap. Is designed for saveing in intent params.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your class `com.example.chalaka.myapplication.Point` does not implement `Parcelable` nor `Serializable`.

Do so and the code above will work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Write this method from where you want to start new Activity:

```
private void gotoServiceFragment(HashMap<String, String> map) {

 Intent gotoService = new Intent(registration.this, Service.class);
 gotoService.putExtra(AndyConstants.MAP, map);
 startActivity(gotoService);

}
```

And to get this **map :**

```
 Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
 HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap<String, String>) bundle.getSerializable(AndyConstants.MAP);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html?hl=en) in your com.example.chalaka.myapplication.Point class.

Answer (score 0):

```
For example, when sending the intent:

HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
hashMap.put("key", "value");
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyOtherActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("map", hashMap);
startActivity(intent);

in MyOtherActivity activity

Intent intent = getIntent();    
HashMap<String, String> hashMap = (HashMap<String, String>) intent.getSerializableExtra("map");
```